# Handler configurations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, app.yaml

I need to forward URLs, but the handlers in my app.yaml file are not accepting any configuration:

```
handlers:
  - url: "/dashboard/([a-z])"
    script: /admin/index.php?page=\1&token=xxx

  - url: "/dashboard/login"
    script: /admin/login.php?token=xxx
```

It only works if you access the full URL.
What's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by not accepting, and only full URL? Do you have errors? If so, can you add them? What is accepted? Do you have examples?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere full work work fine: site.com/admin/login.php?token=xxx
But, not work with: site.com/dashboard/login

Error on gcloud app logs tail -s default :

"GET /dashboard/login HTTP/1.1" 404 191 "-"

Comment: Understood, the url translation isn't performed. Is this page exists `/admin/index.php?page=login&token=xxx`? If so, did you try to delete the 1st handler and to keep only the second one to avoid any conflict?